Which command is better for generating content in ollama
Which command for newsletter generation is best ,Ollama chat or ollama generate
I was creating a rag application which uses ollama in python. I was wondering which command is better for this scenario:

llm_response = ollama.chat(model='mistral', messages=[{'role': 'user', 'content': formatted_prompt}])

llm_response = ollama.generate(model='mistral', prompt=formatted_prompt)


ollama.chat gives faster response but takes less time. Meanwhile generate gives a better output but it is taking way too much time.
I am developing in wsl2 ubuntu, with following specs:

Processor: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700H, 2300 Mhz, 14 Core(s), 20 Logical Processor(s)
RAM: 16 GB
GPU: RTX 3050 Laptop

Any code suggestions are also welcome.
